# Find two words with and without spaces but with word boundary

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex world. So please excuse me. Trying to learn and I have the following requirement

I am trying to come up with a regex that can find both **Cis** and **Cis Female** from the string below.

String: `This usa gender Female male Cis Female a2412421`

I tried:

1. `\bCis(.)*Female\b`
2. `\bCis\s*Female\b`
3. `\bCis(.)*Female\b`
4. `\bCis\b|\bCis Female\b`
5. `(\bCis\b)|(\bCis Female\b)`

After applying the regex the output should be **Cis** and **Cis Female**. Any lead is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `\b((Cis)\s+Female)\b` and use Group 1 and 2. What is your code?

Comment: Why do you want both? If you match Cis Female, you have also matched Cis. If you want to match Cis Female or Cis, this requires a different solution.

Comment: Or use a single capture group `\b(Cis)\s+Female\b` so the whole match is `Cis Female`, and capture group 1 is `Cis` See https://regex101.com/r/sa9vUX/1

Comment: You need something else or is your question answered? √

Comment: @steffen - I took the answer from Wiktor Stribizew as that was the one appeared first when I checked for reply. Upvoted his answer as a token of gratitude.  I  then saw lots of you kind folks who have answered as well. Thanks anyway to all.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "This usa gender Female male Cis Female a2412421", "This usa gender Female male Cis a2412421",
                "This usa gender Female male Cis" };

        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println("Processing '" + s + "' =>");
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(Cis)(\\s+\\w+)?").matcher(s);
            String group = "";
            while (matcher.find()) {
                group = matcher.group();
                if ("Cis Female".equals(matcher.group())) {
                    // ... Perform some operation
                    System.out.println(group);
                } else {
                    // ...Get just 'Cis' and perform some operation
                    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Processing 'This usa gender Female male Cis Female a2412421' =>
Cis Female
Processing 'This usa gender Female male Cis a2412421' =>
Cis
Processing 'This usa gender Female male Cis' =>
Cis
```

Note that the regex, `(Cis)(\s+\w+)?` matches `Cis` followed by optional (one or more whitespace characters which in turn is/are followed by one or more word characters).

Comment: You don't have to use `group.substring(0, 3)` because you use a pattern `(Cis)(\\s+\\w+)?` with 2 capturing groups where `Cis` is in the first group. But reading the question, the OP tried 5 patterns with `Female` in it, so chances are that you can use that string in the pattern. That way you can check if the pattern matches. If it does, the whole match is `Cis Female` and `Cis` is in the group.

Comment: Thanks, @Thefourthbird for the valuable feedback. I've updated the answer to incorporate it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean something like this?

```
String str = "This usa gender Female male Cis Female a2412421";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("((\\bCis\\b)\\s+\\bFemale\\b)").matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) { // or if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // Cis Female
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // Cis
}
```

Here, you match "Cis" and "Cis Female" into two groups. Cis and Female both have a (zero length) word boundary and 1..n whitespace between them.

Some background: You can't match the same part in the input string multiple times in a single matcher call. Consequently you have to apply two regexes. Now you want to match both char sequences with a single regex. This is possible by matching them into different groups as described.